# Method overriding in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, overloading

I have code that looks like this:

```
module A
    def b(a)
      a+1
    end
end
class B
   include A
end
```

I would like to write a method in the class B that looks sort of like this

```
class B
   def b(a)
      if a==2     # are you sure? same result as the old method
         3
      else
         A.b(a)
      end
   end
end
```

How do I go about doing this in Ruby?

Comment: you meant "module A" ... not method A ... ?  And returning '3' in case of a==2 is probably not a good case, because that's the same result as the original b(a) method -- this way you won't see the difference

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want the `super` function, which invokes the 'previous' definition of the function:

```
module A
  def b(a)
    p 'A.b'
  end
end

class B
  include A

  def b(a)
    if a == 2
      p 'B.b'
    else
      super(a) # Or even just `super`
    end
  end
end

b = B.new
b.b(2) # "B.b"
b.b(5) # "A.b"
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that worked with modules. Thought it was only for super classes.

Comment: You don't even need to pass `(a)` to `super`.  Just `super` without any arguments (but no empty parentheses) passes all arguments and any block to the superclass method.

Comment: @vodnik, modules are inserted into the inheritance hierarchy when you call `include`, so generally speaking, they behave like superclasses when used as mixins.

Comment: @d11wtq Thanks for the note on parentheses, guess this would come down to preference, for the sake of clarity I'm gonna leave them in.

Answer (score 3):

```
class B
  alias old_b b  # one way to memorize the old method b , using super below is also possible

  def b(a)
    if a==2
        '3'     # returning a string here, so you can see that it works
    else
      old_b(a)   # or call super here
    end
  end
end



ruby-1.9.2-p0 >   x = B.new
 => #<B:0x00000001029c88> 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 >   x.b(1) 
 => 2 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > x.b(2)
 => "3"
ruby-1.9.2-p0 > x.b(3)
 => 4
```